# What is the purpose of this OOP implementation?

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

Why this instead of that? In the first example, the code is checking for an instantiation of the class object and creating if it doesn't exist. Why is this better than simply instantiating a class object as the second example?

```
public static function instance() {
    if ( is_null( self::$_instance ) ) {
        self::$_instance = new self();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}
```

```
new Class();
```

Comment: Singleton pattern

Comment: This is a pretty dirty singleton. You can archive the same result by declaring a static variable inside the method instead of using class static properties.

Comment: E.g. `static $instance; if ($instance === null) { $instance = new self; } return $instance;`

Comment: Knowing that there's only a single instance floating around can be useful such as if you don't know if there's an existing instance floating around. E.g. a controller might need to access a router to grab the current route etc. Without singleton, or some kind of design pattern, you'd find yourself using global variables or a registry for storing the instance: If global variables, it gets messy to track and can run into conflicts with other code. Keep in mind singleton is usually considered an anti-pattern. Dependency injection is usually a better choice such as for testability etc.